# Is this the correct way to reverse a linkedList recursively?

Tags: data-structures, linked-list

My reverse linked list function seems to be buggy, but even after looking online for solutions, I could not understand why my method fails in a dry run with three nodes :(
In other solutions the starred part is usually written as 'head.next.next = head'. Isn't my line with 'n.next = head' doing the same thing?

Also some other solution had a line before calling the method as:

```
Node secondElem = head.next;
head.next = NULL;
```

I didn't understand why this is needed either :(

I came up with this solution and can't seem to proceed from here:

```
Node reverseLL(Node head){
if (head == NULL || head.next == NULL) return head;
Node n = reverseLL(head.next);
n.next = head; //**
head.next = NULL 
return n;
}
```

Can someone please explain this to me?

Comment: You need to do n = n.next before returning n. You should always take a paper and pen before solving algorithm problems and after you code, you should run through your code.

Comment: Or just return the head instead of n

Comment: correct! but in that case at the end I have a reversed linkedList and a head that points to the tail of the linkedList. So I don't have any trational Head for my linkedList?? i.e I for head=>1 => 2 =>3 => Null, I would have after reverse 3 => 2 => 1 => Null, where head points to Node 1 now!

Answer (score 1):

When you reverse a linked list recursively, you need to attach the former head to the very end. This is something where the result of the reversal of the rest of the list is not really helpful -- in fact you'll just want to return that in the end.

But there is one thing that is important to be aware of: The second element will become the last element of the reversed rest of the list. And `head.next` will still hold a reference to it after reversal of the rest.

**Example**

Original list

```
head = 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> NULL
```

The reversed sublist returned from the recursive call (`head` will still be 1 and `head.next` will still point to 2)

```
3 -> 2 -> NULL
```

You can use this to append the head to the end after the recursive call that reverses the rest:

```
Node reverseLL(Node head) {
  if (head == NULL || head.next == NULL) return head;
  Node n = reverseLL(head.next);
  head.next.next = head;  
  head.next = NULL;
  return n;
}
```

Comment: Isn't ' head.next.next = head; ' the same as my  'n.next = head;'? If not, can you explain that in your answer? So I think my solution is correct after all?

Comment: n is assigned to the result of the reversal of the remainder, which is different from head. In the example, for the top level call, n would point to 3 (asuming the rest would magically work correctly). 3 -> next would be 2, so you'd get 3 -> 1 -> NULL